EF Core 8 and multiple contextes
I'm attempting to get records that don't exist in in a database table and insert them into another table. These are in 2 different databases. I'm using DI and EF Core 8 in a console application.
Code:
var resqProviders = _rESqContext.ProviderInfos.Select(row => row.NcpdpProviderId);

var reconProviders = _reconContext.PharmacyInfos.Select(row => row);

var result = from c in reconProviders 
             where !resqProviders.Contains(c.NcpdpProviderId) 
             select c;

_reconContext.PharmacyInfos.AddRange(result);

_reconContext.SaveChanges();

I keep getting this error and I'm unsure why. Any help is appreciated!

System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot use multiple context instances within a single query execution. Ensure the query uses a single context instance.


If they are on the same server you should consider ausing Cross Database queries, possibly using synonyms.

You need to materialize one of the queries. I suggest you make this edit.
var reconProviders = await _reconContext.PharmacyInfos.Select(row => row).ToListAsync();

Otherwise, EF will not be able to determine which db context instance to use for query translation and execution, hence the error you are seeing.

yep that was the issue!! thanks!!!
